# creating an array inside a while loop(or for loop) then using that array outside

Tags: java, arrays, loops

What I am trying to do, which this won't do and probably never will do, is to create an array using a loop and then calling that array in another class. What would be the best way to go about this. I've looked all over for a solution and they won't compile. Thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    Grow t = new Grow();
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr = t.Grow();
    System.out.print(arr);

}
}

public class Grow{
    static int row;
    static int column;

public ArrayList<Integer> poli(){
        while(row < 51 ){
            int r = row;
                while(column < 1){
                    ArrayList<Integer> policy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    policy.add(r);
                    policy.add(0);

                }

            column-=1;
            row++;
        }

    return policy;

}
```

EDIT:
new problem. 
    Getting error Exception in thread "main"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap   space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3210)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:261)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:235)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:227)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:458)
    at Grow.policy(Grow.java:14)
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){ 

Grow trr = new Grow();
ArrayList arr = trr.policy();
System.out.print(arr);

}
}
```

Here is what I have now. Everything works until I try to make the array in Test class.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grow{
    static int row;
    static int column;

public ArrayList<Integer> policy(){

ArrayList<Integer> policy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(row < 51 ){
          while(column < 1){

                policy.add(row);
                policy.add(0);
                column++; //this addition fixed my problem
            }

        column-=1;
        row++;
    }

return policy;

    }   
}

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
       Grow work= new Grow();
       ArrayList testing= work.policy();
       System.out.print(testing);

    }
}
```

I know it's something simple. I just can't see the solution. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Update. Found the problem. Column only had a decrease of 1 (really could use column--;) which made it loop forever. Added column++ to the code and now it works. Knew it was something simple.

Comment: You can pass around `List`s like any other reference. It's not clear what the issue is.

Comment: The JLS will be one of your best friends. In this case, review the rules on variable scope - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3  Specifically : The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.4) is the rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in the local variable declaration statement.

Comment: When are row and col ever initialized?

Comment: static int initializes them for the entire class so they become a class variable. Default for Int will always be zero @Tezra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize it outside:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> poli(){

    ArrayList<Integer> policy = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while(row < 51 ){
        int r = row;
            while(column < 1){

                policy.add(r);
                policy.add(0);

            }

        column-=1;
        row++;
    }

return policy;

}
```

Also, you don't need a variable to store `row`. `policy.add(row);` will work fine too.

Comment: maybe you can use `List<Integer> policy = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `ArrayList<Integer> policy = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: That worked beautifully. Can't believe I missed that. Now I have another problem though.                                                                                        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Column only had a decrease of 1 (really could use column--;) which made it loop forever. Added column++ to the code and now it works. Knew it was something simple. 
Working code

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grow{
    static int row;
    static int column;

public ArrayList<Integer> policy(){

ArrayList<Integer> policy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while(row < 51 ){
       while(column < 1){

            policy.add(row);
            policy.add(0);
            column++; //this addition fixed my problem
        }

        column-=1;
        row++;
     }

    return policy;

    }   
}

public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
       Grow work= new Grow();
       ArrayList testing= work.policy();
       System.out.print(testing);

    }
}
```